# Can't import data to Rapidminer properly

Tags: csv, import, data-mining, rapidminer

The data I'm trying to import is here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/

```
car.data 51 K
```

There are no missing values in this data, yet there are lots of `"?"s` in the rapidminer once I imported the data. I looked at to the source and those data, which shown as `"?"`, do exist properly in the source. What may be the problem?

by the way, if I download that file it's extension is `.data`. How should I import that kind of files? I import it as if it is a `.csv` file and it looks ok at first but there are those `"?"s`.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file to `car.csv`? Maybe rapidminer makes assumptions based on the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been sometime since I have used `Rapidminer`, but AFAIK, you can import `.data` file by using `csv Import Wizard` and setting the file type to `All Files`.

Regarding the `?` values, you would have the look at the settings while importing the file and  may have to adjust the datatype in `Step 4` of the `Import Wizard` (the dropdown menu)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Read CSV operator to load the file.

In the "Data import wizard - Step 2 of 4 screen, find the **Column Separation** group box and select the radio button **Comma ","**. The default separator is the semicolon and car.csv is comma-separated.

In the next step-- "Data import wizard - Step 3 of 4"-- change the annotation for row 1 from **Name** to **-** (the dash character). This tells RapidMiner that the first row contains data and not column headers.